# TV show about a boy with a monster

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

A kid with fingerless gloves can like summon monsters. There is a bad guy that I think is called like a puppet master. The boy has like a thing with wings.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. This is a very terse description, though. Please take a look at the guidance offered in [this post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/122024) and then edit your question to add any more details you can recall.

Comment: Dinosaur KIng has a male protagonist who wears fingerless gloves and summons things; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6tACcx_u4xM

Comment: Pokemon has a male protagonist who wears fingerless gloves and summons things; https://www.fortressofsolitude.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/ash-ketchum-pokemon.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a couple of answers in comments so I'm having a try.

I'm guessing [Slugterra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slugterra), again the hero has fingerless gloves and has various monsters he battles bad guys with.

Comment: https://slugterra.fandom.com/wiki/The_Unbeatable_Master